# How do I add another avatar to the wordpress default ones?

Tags: wordpress, gravatar

I want to put some good avatar instead of the wordpress default. How can i do this without touching the core.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very easy, you don't have touch the core. Just use the `avatar_defaults` filter.

There is post on that [here](http://wordpresskillertips.blogspot.com/2010/10/add-new-avatars-to-your-wordpress-and.html)

```
/**
* add a default-gravatar to options
*/
if ( !function_exists('fb_addgravatar') ) {
function fb_addgravatar( $avatar_defaults ) {
$myavatar = get_bloginfo('template_directory') . '/images/avatar.gif';
$avatar_defaults[$myavatar] = 'people';

$myavatar2 = get_bloginfo('template_directory') . '/images/myavatar.png';
$avatar_defaults[$myavatar2] = 'wpengineer.com';

return $avatar_defaults;
}

add_filter( 'avatar_defaults', 'fb_addgravatar' );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to Settings -> Discussion and scroll to the bottom. You'll see a Default Avatar section. Select something there. I like the Identicon option. This will still show the users gravatar if he or she has one.

BTW: Identicons are what you see if a user doesn't set an avatar here on StackOverflow.